# Why don't the crew of Moya know the location of their homeworlds?

Tags: farscape

In the Farscape season 1 episode 'DNA Mad Scientist' the crew of Moya exchange DNA samples in exchange for maps to their homeworlds. Given that all of their species seem to be well known in the galaxy, how is it that the locations of their homeworlds are unknown? If it was just that Moya lacked the information, why could they not get it elsewhere? The way the crew acted (attacking Pilot and turning on each other) suggested that this was their only chance to return home.

Comment: Do you know the location of yours?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica - yup - here.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica (0, 0, 0) of course!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The issue isn't that they don't know where their planets are (well, in John's case that's precisely the issue) but that they don't know, given that they're in the "Uncharted Territories" where they are ***in relation to their homeworlds***.

> **Tahleen:** *We have no star charts or **reference points home to Delvia**. We prefer not to wander.*
>
> **John:** (as he turns to leave) *Oh, that makes sense. I mean hell - everybody's lost in this corner of the universe anyway.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Farscape: Rhapsody In Blue](http://transcripts.terrafirmascapers.com/112.htm)</sup></sub>

Without a reliable map, starburst is little more than random jumping and even if they head in what they know to be broadly the right direction, they're more likely to end up back in jail when they jump through Peacekeeper-held territory.

> **NamTar:** *Provide you with a genetic map to your home world? A map that will allow you **to make the journey and avoid any Peacekeeper jurisdictions** along the way? That is what you came here for, isn't it?*
>
> <sub><sup>[DNA Mad Scientist](http://transcripts.terrafirmascapers.com/109.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: Analogy: You're kidnapped and imprisoned in Siberia in the year 1800. You have no idea exactly where in Siberia, you just know it's cold, and remote. You escape. You need to get home to Paris, France, all you've got is a compass, and every government east of Switzerland is trying to kill you. You know you need to head roughly west, but knowing which routes are safe, which aren't patrolled, where you currently *are*? Unless you've literally memorized a topographical map of all of Asia, you're going to need some help. And that's just on planet Earth, which is *easy*.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that should be an answer!

Comment: @RonJohn - It is an answer. It's *my* answer :-)

Comment: It's your answer with different words.  Possibly it should be added to your answer.